# Как удалить сообщение из группы?

Tags: telegram-bot

Подскажите пожалуйста, что и где нужно настроить(дать разрешение), чтобы бот мог удалять сообщения из "GROUP"?

[api#deletemessage](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#deletemessage) - работает в канале, но в группе почему-то, нет. Боту везде даны права администратора, что подразумевает эту возможность по дефолту:

```
- If the bot is an administrator of a group, it can delete any message there.
```

Пробовал так же менять [privacy mode](https://core.telegram.org/bots#privacy-mode). Всегда возвращает:

```
{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: message can't be deleted"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Помимо указанного выше, оказывается, что бот не только должен иметь статус администратора группы, но и в настройках группы должна НЕ быть отмечена опция:

```
Все участники являются администраторами.
```

Comment: Ну как же, вопрос содержит все включения из документации, выполнение которых необходимо для требуемой операции, но в моём случае этого не происходило. Длилось это до тех пор, пока я случайно не убрал галочку в настройках, о которой нигде не упоминается, о чём не преминул сообщить, завершив тем самым полноту картины действительно участвующих условий.